# How can I calculate the pi value in R using Leibniz's formula?

Tags: r

I'm new to programming in R, my question is how can I estimate the value of pi in R using operations between vectors, including the "sum" function? with n = 0:10000000

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80. Then show us what you have tried.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To keep something left for you to do your homework, lets take a look at the formula
.

[image]

create a vector v from 1 to n (n=10000000) with steps of 2 so you get:
`v <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...)` (take a look at `seq.int` function)

then alternate the sign of the alternating (tip! multiplying vectors of different lengths recycle the shorter vector) and you get:
`v <- c(1, -3, 5, -7, 9, ...)`

take the inverse of v and take the sum, multiply it by 4 to get pi